# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'

Tags: python, imblearn

I tried to handle imbalanced dataset using imblearn as:

```
nm = NearMiss(random_state=42)
X_bal,Y_bal = nm.fit_sample(x,y)
```

But I am getting an unexpected error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

How to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: NearMiss class does not has the key word parameter `random_state`, you can refer the docs [here](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.NearMiss.html).

Answer (score 0):

we first import:

```
from imblearn import under_sampling as us

us.NearMiss(
    *,
    sampling_strategy='auto',
    version=1,
    n_neighbors=3,
    n_neighbors_ver3=3,
    n_jobs=None,
)
```

you have use this keyword/parameters in the `.__init__()`

**so to your problem:**

NearMiss custuctor dont take random_state as a parameter wich gives you that the **init** dont expect that as a keyword.